# How to implement dynamic UITTableViews inside a ScrollView with a dynamic amount of 'pages'

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been trying implement an interface that displays data in `UITableView`s with custom `UITTableViewCell`s inside a `ScrollView` (linked to a `Page Control` for clarity).

I've found a couple of tutorials that showed how to implement these feature separate from one another but not together and I didn't really find anything on how to load a couple of custom `UITableView` into a controller.  My basic approach now comes down to this inside the `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    SceduleTableView *sceduleTable = [[SceduleTableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [sceduleTable setDelegate:sceduleTable];
    [sceduleTable setDataSource:sceduleTable];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:sceduleTable];
}
```

I've been testing with 4 pages, but these will be turned into a dynamic amount after I can work this out.

SceduleTableView inherits from `UITableView` and has datasource that gets an array with objects out of a local sqlite database. I've got the part working where the all the SceduleTableViews load the data for each of them, but at the moment the build fails and returns this error:

```
2012-08-13 15:43:18.975 basis[2055:f803] -[SceduleTableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bc4800
2012-08-13 15:43:18.976 basis[2055:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SceduleTableView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bc4800'
```

That function doesn't really do much, but even the NSLog is never reached:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Should have %d rows", sceduleItems.count);
    return sceduleItems.count;
}
```

And I know that both the array that I try to fill the table with isn't empty and that the SceduleTableView instances aren't nil (I read that this could've been the problem). These logs return this for each SceduleTableView

```
NSLog(@"Array sceduleItems contains %d", sceduleItems.count);
NSLog(@"Trying to reload. Self = %@", self);
[self reloadData];

2012-08-13 15:49:32.183 basis[2259:f803] Array sceduleItems contains 340
2012-08-13 15:49:32.184 basis[2259:f803] Trying to reload. Self = <SceduleTableView: 0xbabb800; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (960 0; 320 440); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e29660>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

I'm very new at iOS development and to be honest I'm really not sure if even my approach is the right one. Feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system tries to call the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. You have not defined that. You have defined the method `numberOfRowsInSection:`, overwriting UITableView's default implementation. Please don't do that.

You should define

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Should have %d rows", sceduleItems.count);
    return sceduleItems.count;
}
```

in your DataSource.

Also, many developers would probably frown upon your using your table view objects as their own delegates and datasources. Perhaps you would like to familiarize yourself with the [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) paradigm for a more usual design alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I meant to overwrite it properly. I must have not being paying attention.

Also, thanks for pointing out the proper reading material. I'll plunge into it tomorrow.